# Creating new docs without auto-ids without accidentally referencing an existing doc

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

If I have a collections of docs in which I provide the ids (i.e. not the Firestore auto ids), how can I be certain to create a new doc rather than referencing an existing one?

For instance if I have a collection `foo` with a document id `bar`, I can reference it as (given db is the injected AngularFirestore service) `this.db.doc('foo/bar')`.

Then later I want to create another `foo` doc, I can check if it already exists with something like

```
checkExits(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const docRef = this.db.doc(`foo/${id}`);
  return docRef.snapshotChanges().map(change => change.payload.exists);
}
```

However in the time that I check that it exists, to creating the doc, isn't it possible that it gets created? Such that when I try to create the new doc, it is instead referencing an existing one and overwriting it? i.e. `this.db.doc('foo/bar').set({})`

How can I create new docs specifying the id, while avoiding referencing existing docs (and throwing an error if it exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for that. Within the transaction you first call [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get) on the location, to ensure [nothing exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~exists) yet. Then you [write to the same location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#set), to create the document.